# Qt/OpenGL issue. Primitive isnt rendering unless the QGLWidget is shown first

Tags: qt, opengl, vbo, vao

So I have a Qt Application with multiple tabs.  In one of tabs I have a QGLWidget where Im trying to render a primitive using VAO/VBOs.

My initialization code looks like this:

```
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glGenBuffers(2, buffer);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size() * sizeof(float), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);  // Unbind VAO
```

And my draw code in the paintGL() loop is like this:

```
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices/3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

This works fine as long as my tab with the QGLWidget is shown first.  However, if the QGlWidget is not show first this wont work.  The VAO/VBO initialization happens correctly (Ive checked this with glGetError() and things look okay), however, because the draw/paint loop doesn't get called immediately after (I have to switch to the GL Tab for paintGL to trigger the draw), nothing renders at all when I switch to the GL tab.  Again, if I make the QGLWidget the first tab, the draw gets triggered almost immediately after I initialize and everything renders fine.

Why would this be? Am I missing something here? Is there some reason why initializing a VAO/VBOs doesnt work if the draw loop/paintGL isn't gonna happen immediately after?

I think I should also mention that Im NOT using shaders. This is a legacy application so Im slowly starting to update it. First step was to get the vertices to the card. Originally we were using calls to glEnableClientState instead of VAO/VBOs, but my transformations are all handled through the matrix stack and color is specified through glColor.